# Is there any way to move the search box in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As you can see in the below image, the search box is at the top right corner.
[image: Find box]

Sometimes this image will cover up the text underneath it. Is there a way to move the search box to some other place? For example, like Atom's or Sublime's search box.

Comment: You can restrict the global search to just search one file. That way you end up with a local search in the sidebar. Granted this is more fiddly than just using the local search.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NO**, there is currently no way to move it.

There was discussion on this amongst the vscode developers: [Find Widget UI enhancement](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26498).

---

> We should definitely not make this move both vertically and
>   horizontally since we do not do this anywhere else in our UX.
>   Introducing such a new concept does not align well with our general
>   workbench UX which is not very flexible

---

> Looking at the pictures the docked find widget at the top / bottom
>   feel too heavy for me.
>
> The current find widget solution I like because it is similar to the
>   chrome experience which every user on the planet is familiar with

---

> While implementing the docking solution, we found we can actually
>   split this two issues completely. For the issue of covering search
>   result, we can allow users to scroll beyond the first line by the
>   height of Find Widget. It doesn't change Find Widget at all, you can
>   only scroll beyond first line only when the Find Widget is visible so
>   it won't cover anything.

---

> I made two changes to the Find Widget for this work item.
>
> - You can resize the Find widget horizontally
> - You can scroll beyond the first line when the find widget is visible.

---

Which gives us the only customizations we can do to the search/find widget if it (as you said) "*covers up text underneath it*":

- You can adjust the width horizontally
- You can set [`"editor.find.addExtraSpaceOnTop": true`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings) to allow "*scroll beyond the first line when the Find Widget is visible*"

Answer (score 1):

This problem is unsolved as the addExtraSpaceOnTop option does not really address the fundamental issue. When the find widget covers up code it makes it development more difficult for the user. For example, when you're undoing and redoing changes with +'Z' and +'Y', if those changes happen to be under the find widget, your ability to quickly review the changes you implemented is impacted.

The simplest fix would be to always give the find widget the *whole* top row (or two) of the editing window. Another fix would be to make the widget semi-transparent so that you can see through it well enough to spot when the text that is hidden behind it has changed or has been highlighted.