# How to move the 'find' widget

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to search for some string, and this string exists in the very first line of the code, the find widget pops up, but it covers the string I'm looking for.

[image]

Is there any way of defining the position of the find widget? Or maybe it can be moved into top/side bar like it is done in Sublime text?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I did not see it. Shall I remove my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate Question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55913723/is-there-anyway-to-mhe-search-box-in-visual-studio-codeove-t). There is not way to remove it. You can:

- Resize the Find widget horizontally
- Scroll beyond the
  first line when the find widget is visible